# Apparently simple function not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, function

I'm sure I'm just having a moment, but I can't figure this out for anything. I wanted to create a quick function to sum up a particular JSON object's values over an array, but it returns nothing. Here's the code:

```
var a=[{"b":"23"},{"b":"37"}]
function sumJSON(json,elem){
    var total=0;
    $.each(json,function(index,item){
        var count=index+1;
        total+=Number(item[elem]);
        if(count===json.length){
            return total;
        }
    })
}
console.log(sumJSON(a,"b"));
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/demnj231/)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want this to be solved with plain javascript.

```js
var a = [{"b":"23"},{"b":"37"}]

function sumJSON(a,key) {
  return a.reduce((s, data) => s + (+data[key]), 0)
}

console.log(sumJSON(a, 'b'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of .reduce()

Comment: Pls do read "Array.reduce", "Array.map", "Array.filter"
These will help you tackle most of the javascript problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[{"b":"23"},{"b":"37"}]
function sumJSON(json,elem){
    var total=0;
    $.each(json,function(index,item){
        total+=Number(item[elem]);
    })
    return total;
}
console.log(sumJSON(a,"b"));
```

$each needs not to return anything, just calls a function for each member of the collection, you need to return the total after the call to $.each, once the function has been called for all the elements

Comment: Since JS is asynchronous, doesn't that risk the total being returned before $.each is completed? Or have I misunderstood asynchronous in this context?

Comment: @vurtual $.each is not asynchronous, it will get executed once per each element before going to the next line. It would be different for example if you called an asynchronous function inside $.each. 
In fact, you can check it yourself [here](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.each) :)

No async code there ;)

Comment: I must be mixing ajax with js in my head. The amount of times I’ve coded: if (index +1 == array.length) unnecessarily!